# Rails: query params in the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to get routes like the following:

```
http://example.org/test/url/p/some-123/random-444/keys-245
```

and this url should be resolved to params:

```
{
  controller:"home",
  action:"get",
  mod:"test",
  submob:"url",
  some:"123",
  random:"444",
  keys:"245"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get ':mod/:submod/p/*extra_params', to: 'home#index'`

Then in your `HomeController`

```
def params
  orig_params = super
  extra_params = orig_params.delete(:extra_params)
  extra_params = Hash[extra_params.split('/').map { |p| p.split('-') }]
  orig_params.merge(extra_params)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure - you'll have to define it all in your [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :controller do
    get ":mod(/:submod/:some/:keys)", to "controller#action"
end
```

Comment: This is close, but what if I have random key params?

Answer (score 1):

Can we use this

```
  match '/:mod/:submod/:some/:keys' => "controller#action", :as => test_profile
```

and we use it like

```
 link_to "Own path", test_profile_path(mod: "test", submod: "url", some: "123", keys: "245")
```

Comment: I have random params keys with `-` and `/` delimiters.